# Rotate JLabel 90 Degrees Java

Tags: java, swing, rotation, jlabel, imageicon

I have an image within a Jlabel which I want to rotate 90 degrees right when the user hits the button. I've attempted it myself, but with various errors. I was told the best way to do it was to use Graphics2D?

Main Class:

```
private void SearchButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {        
BufferedImage image;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(file);
            Image scaled = image.getScaledInstance(Jlabel1.getWidth(), Jlabel1.getHeight(), 5);
            Jlabel1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(scaled));
```

Button:

```
 private void rotateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        Graphics2D userImage = (Graphics2D)JLabel1.getGraphics();
    userImage.rotate(Math.toRadians(90));
    userImage.drawImage(JLabel1, JLabel1.getHeight(), JLabel1.getWidth());
    }
```

Comment: *"aren't even worth posting"*  Leads to the feeling 'not even worth answering'.

Comment: "arent even worth posting" meaning they were well off what was needed........

Comment: So you basically decided to post nothing of relevant code, and ask us how to do this. So I am missing some crucial information: where do I need to send my invoice to ?

Comment: I'm not asking you to code it for me. I'm just simply asking if Graphics2D is the best method of getting such result.

Answer (score 2):

You should never ever use Component.getGraphics() for drawing on a component. Instead, you should always overwrite paintComponent and work with the Graphics object that gets passed to it.

> Component.getGraphics() simply can't work. Java uses a callback
>   mechanism for drawing graphics. You are not supposed to "push"
>   graphics information into a component using getGraphics(). Instead you
>   are supposed to wait until Java calls your paint()/paintComponent()
>   method. At that moment you are supposed to provide the Component with
>   the drawings you would like to do.
>
> This mechanism is necessary so Java can support graphics systems which
>   don't remember window contents when it is obscured (e.g. overlayed by
>   another window). When the window becomes visible again, such graphics
>   systems have to ask the application to reconstruct the window content.
>   Therefore, paint()/paintComponent() is supposed to be the memory of a
>   component. getGraphics(), however, doesn't have any recollection of
>   previous drawing operations. So once a drawing done via getGraphics()
>   is lost, it can't be reconstructed. There is nothing in there that
>   stores the old drawing data, and there is nothing in AWT/Swing which
>   informs getGraphics() to do some re-drawing.
>
> In addition, there are situations where Component.getGraphics() simply
>   returns null. This is a defined behavior of the method. And finally,
>   most users of getGraphics() forget to dispose the Graphics object
>   after usage.

http://www.pscode.org/guifaq.html